# VBA: Return an array into a spreadsheet from a function

Tags: vba

I am trying to improve my VBA using a book called "How to Implement Market Models Using VBA" but I am having some issues with arrays. In particular, something that I have also tried to do in the past unsuccessfully, is to return an array from a function.

Luckily, an extract of the book is available on Google Books at [this link](https://books.google.ch/books?id=CAVhBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=DailyVar+vba&source=bl&ots=NPGHdDmqxJ&sig=ACfU3U0dzDQOs8YIk5JSNQ832RtNp12sHg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkgK7dtaXkAhVH6qQKHdC1A_EQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=DailyVar%20vba&f=false)

```vb
Function DailyVar(Quotes!()) As Single()

ReDim t!(UBound(Quotes))

For i = 1 To UBound(t)
    t(i) = (Quotes(i) - Quotes(i - 1)) / Quotes(i - 1)
Next i

DailyVar = t

End Function
```

The code above is the on that I am trying from the book. However, if in a spreadsheet I use =DailyVar(some range with numbers) in a cell, the result is "#VALUE!". I tried to run the function in a range and using CTRL+Shift+Enter like for matrices in Excel but it doesn't work.

How can I return arrays from functions into a spreadsheet? What am I doing wrong such that the code above doesn't work?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are returned using variants

```
Function DailyVar(Quotes()) As Variant
Dim i As Long
ReDim t(UBound(Quotes))

For i = 1 To UBound(t)
    t(i - 1) = (Quotes(i) - Quotes(i - 1)) / Quotes(i - 1)
Next i

DailyVar = t

End Function

Sub test()
Dim q(3)
q(0) = 3
q(1) = 2
q(2) = 1
Range("b1:d1").Formula = DailyVar(q)
End Sub
```

EDIT - using a range rather than an array

```
Public Function DailyVar(Q As Range) As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim Quotes As Variant
Quotes = Q 'fill quotes as array - this is a 2D array even for a single row or column of cells
ReDim t(UBound(Quotes))

For i = 2 To UBound(t)
    t(i - 2) = (Quotes(i, 1) - Quotes(i - 1, 1)) / Quotes(i - 1, 1)
Next i

DailyVar = t
'or if you want them down a column
'DailyVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(t)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Your solution works in the subroutine but I cannot make it work calling in from a cell in the spreadsheet as =DailyVar(some cells). Is it possible to do so?

Comment: To use in a cell you need to enter it over the correct number of cells as an arrayfunction (control-shift enter)

Comment: This is what I tried but I get "#VALUE!" everywhere. That's why I thought there may have been an issue in the VBA code.

Comment: Two possibilities: across not down - the array is returned as a set of cells across the spreadsheet not down a column. And how are you passing Quotes?

Comment: I tried both horizontally and vertically and I keep getting "#VALUE!". I am passing Quotes as a range of cells. I would like to get the output from selecting the values in a range, e.g. =DailyVar(A1:A10).